# How can I make an output to print +1 every time I do an onkeydown Event in javascript?

Tags: javascript, events, onkeydown

What I need is to make an onkeydown Event that when I press the key m, it will print a +1 in the output

the output in the html is:

```
<h1 id="moreNum">how many times have you pressed the "m": 0</h1>
```

and when I type m, it will print this: how many times have you pressed the "m": 1

if I click it again it will print: how many times have you pressed the "m": 2

and so on

Comment: `document.getElementById("moreNum").addEventListener("keydown", myFunction);` after that you could define the function the way you want `function myFunction() {
 //increase your counter
}`

Comment: I tried this: let outputElement = document.getElementById("moreNum");
    outputElement.innerHTML = 'how many times have you pressed the "m": ' += 1 ;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `addEventLisetner` and increment the count only if the key pressed is `m` using `key` provided by the `event` object.

```js
const h1 = document.querySelector("#moreNum");
let count = 0;

function setText(times) {
  h1.textContent = `how many times have you pressed the "m": ${times}`
}

function logKey(e) {
  if (e.key === 'm') {
    ++count;
    setText(count);
  }

}

document.addEventListener('keydown', logKey);
```

```html
<h1 id="moreNum">how many times have you pressed the "m": 0</h1>
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work :)

```
<h1 id="moreNum">how many times have you pressed the "m": <span id="counter"></span></h1>


let count = 0;
document.addEventListener('keydown', logKey);

function logKey(e) {
  if (e.which === 77) {
    count = count + 1
    document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML = count
    
  }
}
```